# How many walks of length 3 are there between two distinct vertices in a complete graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Let $v,w$ be two distinct vertices in the complete graph $K_n$, where $n \geq 3$. How many walks of length 3 are there from $v$ to $w$?

It is explained as follows. Let $v, x, y, w$ be walk of length 3 from $v$ to $w$. If $x=w$ then there are $n-1$ choices for $y \neq w$. if $x \neq w $ then there are $n-2$ choices for $x \neq v, w$. So, total the number of choices is $n-1 + (n-2)^2 = n^2 -3n +3$.

I get the $n-1$ part because a vertex cannot go to itself since there are no loops in a complete graph. But how do we get the other part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the quoted solution, consider $2$ cases . . .

Case $(1):\;x=w$.

Then $y$ can be any vertex other than $w$, so $n-1$ choices.

Case $(2):\;x \ne w$.

Then there are $n-2$ choices for $x$ since by assumption, $x \ne w$, and also, we can't have $x=v$, but all other choices are possible.

Once $x$ is chosen, $y$ can't equal $x$, and $y$ can't equal $w$, but all other choices are possible, so there are $n-2$ choices for $y$.

Thus, case $(2)$ yields $(n-2)^2$ choices.

Summing the results for the two cases, the number of walks of length $3$ from $v$ to $w$ is 
$$(n-1)+(n-2)^2 = n^2-3n+3$$

Comment: Why do we multiply $(n-2)(n-2)$?

Comment: For case $(2)$, there are $n-2$ choices for $x$, and for each such choice, there are $n-2$ choices for $y$, so the multiplication rule is applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively: As $x$ can be anything but $v,$ there are $n-1$ choices for $x.$ Likewise, as $y$ can be anything but $w,$ there are $n-1$ choices for $y.$ Any $x$ can be paired with any $y,$ **provided** $x\ne y.$ There are $(n-1)^2$ pairs $(x,y),$ and $n-2$ of those pairs have $x=y,$ so the number of walks is $(n-1)^2-(n-2)=n^2-3n+3.$

Comment: Could you explain how did you get $n-2$ so that it is a closed walk?

Comment: What's this about closed walks? I didn't see anything about closed walks in the question. You asked about walks from $v$ to $w$ where $v$ and $w$ are two **distinct** vertices.

Comment: The $n-2$ in my answer comes from the fact that $(n-1)^2$ counts things like $v,x,y,w$ where $v\ne x=y\ne w,$ that is $v,x,x,w$ where $x\ne y$ and $x\ne w.$ There are $n-2$ vertices which are $\ne v$ and $\ne w.$